# Absolute path reference for files on Android with Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap

I have an external Web based app using PhoneGap and Cordova.  On iOS, I have no problem referencing local files, such as image files in the package.  I include the Cordova **cordova-plugin-file** and on the external web server I reference the local image files with the path **cdvfile://localhost/bundle/www/img/** such as the img syntax below:

```
<img src="cdvfile://localhost/bundle/www/img/news.jpg">
```

But, I ***cannot seem to make it work for an Android***.  I have tried the following methods and other similar paths, but no success.

```
<img src="file://localhost/assets/www/img/news.jpg">
<img src="cdvfile://localhost/assets/www/img/news.jpg">
<img src="file:///localhost/assets/www/img/news.jpg">
<img src="file:///android_assets/www/img/news.jpg">
```

Key items in my config.xml file include:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm"/>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" source="npm"/>
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
```

In the index.html file - my Content Security Policy is:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap://ready file:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' data:; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

Relative file path references on the html pages on the local system work fine, but when I go to the external web site and WebView app I can't reference the localhost absolute path correctly for an Android.  I can do it on iOS, but can't figure it out for Android.

Any suggestions on how to access local files in the app package on an Android with an absolute path?

Answer (score 0):

Try using relative paths in the following format,

```
<img src="assets/www/img/news.jpg">
```

I had a similar issue with locale json's and it resolved like this.

Put the assets once again with this format in the **www** directory and try doing another clean Android build. (Removing the **android** directory, adding the Cordova Android platform again, and rebuilding)

Comment: Thank you, but that has not worked for me.  I can't use the relative path because the app transitions to an external web server link.  So now any relative path to a file is on the external web server and does not link to the local file.  I'm looking to use the local file and not a file on the web server.  Any other ideas on how to get to the local file would be great.

Comment: @StephenSmith did you found a solution? Have same issue here..